# multiple matrix row by row and column by column in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to multiply 2 matrix with element of row by row and col by col as below

```
N = 100; r = [ [0.5] , [0.01] , [0.04] , [0.01] ]; 
x1 = np.random.randn(4,N);
x2 = np.tile(r,(1,N));
x = np.multiply(np.array(x1),np.array(x2));
```

2 matrices are 4 x 100,  when i test with  small matrix the result was true, however with big matrix, i always got wrong result.

```
x1 = [ [1] , [0.5] , [3] , [0] ];
x2 = [ [2] , [0] , [2] , [3] ];
x = np.multiply(np.array(x1),np.array(x2));
```

> result is : x = [ [2] , [0] , [6] , [0] ] ;

Appreciate thank for your help.

Comment: Can you make an example with a 2 x 2 matrices and give us the expected result ?

Comment: Please post the expected answer for a small example so that we may know if you are actually doing what you want.

Comment: Sorry, It is still true, however the number is fixed like -4.9920003-03 or 3.114034-02.

Comment: How are you testing the result?